# How do I open an RSS feed in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, feed

I am trying to make an RSS reader. I have already created a UTI called `foo.feed` with `public.mime-type` of `application/rss+xml` and `public.filename-extension` of `rss`. I have also set up my app to open the `feed` URL scheme. However, when I click a link to an RSS feed in Safari, it first asks me if I want to open it in News. When I click "No", it says "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: No, I eventually gave up.

Comment: How did you add the UTI type?